# Como puedo permitir el ingreso de la letra ñ en java?

Tags: java

Buenas tengo un `textField` que recibe el apellido del cliente, y necesito que el cliente pueda ingresar la **letra ñ**. Tengo una validacion en el evento `keytyped` del `JtextField` el cual solo permite ingresar letras, funciona con todas las letras pero cuando intento ingresar la letra ñ no puedo. Como podria hacer para que tambien me permita ingresar la ñ?

este es la validacion que tengo en el `textField`:

```
    private void txtApellido2KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
    
    char c = evt.getKeyChar();
    if ((c < 'a' || c > 'z') && (c < 'A' || c > 'Z') && (c != 32)) { 
        evt.consume();//no permite que se ingrese 
    }

    if (txtApellido2.getText().length() >= 25) { //permite ingresar solo 25 caracteres
        evt.consume();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar [Unicode](https://pro.arcgis.com/es/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/overview/a-quick-tour-of-unicode.htm#:%7E:text=Unicode%20es%20un%20sistema%20de,sistemas%20de%20escritura%20del%20mundo.) para reemplazar por las letras que deseas, en el cual tú código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
private void txtApellido2KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
        char c = evt.getKeyChar();
        if ((c < 'a' || c > 'z') && (c < 'A' || c > 'Z') && (c != 32)&& (c!='\u00f1')&&(c!='\u00d1')) { 
            evt.consume();//no permite que se ingrese 
        }

        if (txtApellido2.getText().length() >= 25) { //permite ingresar solo 25 caracteres
            evt.consume();
        }
}
```

La letra ñ/Ñ en Unicode:

1. ñ -> u00f1
2. Ñ -> u00d1

Comment: Gracias me funciono bien

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes resolver de la siguiente manera:

**Código:**

```
  private void txtApellido2KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                          
        Character letra = evt.getKeyChar();
        char numero = evt.getKeyChar();

        if(Character.isLetter(letra) || (evt.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) ||
            (evt.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || (evt.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_MINUS)
            || !(evt.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN)){
            evt.setKeyChar(Character.toUpperCase(letra));
        }else{
            evt.consume();
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }

        if(Character.isDigit(numero)){
            evt.consume();
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }

        if(textfield_nombre.getText().length()>=25){
            evt.consume();
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
    }
```

También podrías controlar la **letra Ñ/ñ** mediante el código `ASCII`:

- ñ -> 164
- Ñ -> 165